# If a monk is dual-wielding a long sword and short sword, do they still get unarmed strike?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

If a monk PC has a short sword in one hand and a long sword in the other with two-weapon fighting, do they still get Martial Arts?

Comment: What do you mean by "with two weapon fighting"? Note that ["Two-Weapon Fighting"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) (TWF) refers to a particular rule in 5e, which longswords don't meet the requirement for, as they don't have the "light" property. (Only the Dual Wielder feat overrides this.) This is particularly important to the question, as TWF uses your action and bonus action, so we need to understand if TWF is what you mean here.

Comment: Seems clear that they mean “two weapon fighting”. A question making an error doesn’t always indicate that maybe they mean something else. Answers can correct misapprehensions in the process of solving the problem.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Their title refers to "dual-wielding" (not a technical term in 5e) and their post body refers to TWF, so I wouldn't say it's necessarily clear at all that they actually mean TWF in both cases.

Comment: @V2Blast I’m unaware of a meaning of “dual wielding” that doesn’t mean fighting with a weapon in each hand. If there is, then it might be ambiguous, but given that they’re using the two terms interchangeably and their description of the situation describes using a weapon in each hand, even then any potential ambiguity would be resolved.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: You can "dual-wield" if you have Extra Attack, simply wielding both weapons at once and potentially attacking once with each weapon as their Attack action; such dual-wielding has no necessary interaction with the TWF rule, which uses up one's bonus action.

Comment: @V2Blast We shouldn’t default to assuming that people mean unusual maneuvers when there’s an obvious superficial reading that makes full sense, especially when the rest of the post makes it clear that they’re novices.

Answer (score 11):

**No, a Monk wielding a short sword *and* a longsword on a turn does not get to also use their martial arts.**

According to the martial arts ability description for monks in the PHB (pg 78):

> At 1st level, your practice of martial arts gives you master of combat styles that use unarmed strikes and monk weapons, **which are shortswords and any simple melee weapons that don't have two-handed or heavy propery.**
>
> When you use the Attack action with an unarmed strike or a monk weapon on your turn, you can make one unarmed strike as a bonus action.

Note the "any simple melee weapons." In the equipment section, Longswords fall under the martial weapons, not the simple weapons. The only exception to this, is if the monk chooses the Way of the Kensei (Xanthar's Guide to Everything, Pg. 34), where the monk can pick any two weapons to become their Kensei weapons. Kensei weapons also count as monk weapons.

> Choose two types of weapons to be your kensei weapons: one melee and one ranged. Each of these weapons can be any simple or martial weapon that lacks the heavy and special properties... Weapons of the chosen type are monk weapons for you.

As for the dual wielding, you have to choose what you're doing with your bonus action. When attacking with dual wielding, you're using a bonus action to attack with the off hand weapon. (PHB 195) Normally, you also have to have both weapons as light weapons, but if you take the Dual Wielder feat (PHB 165), you can get away with a Longsword and a shortsword. This still means that you're deciding what to use your bonus action for. You only have one, and if you spent it to attack with the off hand shortsword, you cannot use your marital arts in that same turn.

So for a Way of the Kensei Monk who chose Longsword as one of their kensei weapons, and taking the Dual Wielder feat, the monk can carry both a Longsword and a shortsword. But when attacking, the monk is still either attacking with Longsword and Shortsword, or Longsword and martial arts.

Comment: I think an essential part of the *Martial Arts* feature is the "You gain the following benefits while you are unarmed or wielding only monk weapons". If you're not a kensei monk with longswords as a kensei weapon, you simply gain no benefits from *Martial Arts* even if you're just holding a longsword.

Comment: For the Kensei Weapons ability on XGtE, pg 34 says "... Weapons of the chosen type are monk weapons for you." Only for a Kensei monk would holding a Longsword allow you to still benefit from Martial Arts.

Comment: that's ... precisely what I stated in my comment? Or am I confusing something here?